# Will the total transition from ground to excited state decrease when two potential energy surface come near to each other?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I am trying to study Tully simple avoided crossing model via mean-field dynamics. I see when two surfaces are near when value of parameter C is 0.0005 (Unavoided/trivial crossings) there is less transition to excited state whereas, when the surfaces are further, i.e. C=0.05 then I see more transition. This seems counter intuitive.Is it the breakdown of Born-oppenheimer interaction and Ehrenfest(meanfield dynamics)?